# Total distance of Cycling routes in European Cities

Tags: transportation

I managed to find a lot of stats about cycling in Europe, however, not what I was looking for.

I need an open dataset with the total length of the cycling routes in each European City (or at least some of them)

For example,

```
City, TotalLength
London, 84km
Berlin, 72km
Paris, 34km
....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to get data from OpenStreetMap: the https://www.openstreetmap.org

Data can be downloaded per country or region on GeoFabrik.de: https://www.geofabrik.de/

There is even a nice python package called OSMNX to deal with road network (including bike ways where available): https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
You can select road with their OSM attributes and within certain specific area using selections. More information on the doc.

There is as well the overpass API: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API
which you may give a try on overpass-turbo: https://overpass-turbo.eu/

There still be some learning curve for these tools, so feel free to experiment and read documentations about them.